# When releasing an App update, can my data in the bundle path change or get deleted?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsbundle

I'm getting ready to release a new update for my app which stores data in the local bundle path and I want to ensure the data stored in this path isn't deleted when they update. Can this happen and what should I watch out for?

This is the code I'm using to get the path to store data:

```
// Temporary method variables
NSError *error;

// Create a list of paths
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

// Get the path to the apps documents directory from the array
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// Create a full path to the file
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FFUserPrefs.plist"];

// Access the file manager
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Check if the file exists and if not, copy from the bundle path to the documents path
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
{
    // Get path to file from bundle directory
    NSString *pathBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FFUserPrefs" ofType:@"plist"];

    // Copy pref file to app documents folder
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:pathBundle toPath:path error:&error];
}
```

I'm just afraid that the data my users have stored in this directory could be lost and want to make sure it is still there after updating. The only reason I ask is because after running my new build via xCode on my phone that had the release application installed, it wiped out the data and started fresh. What am I missing? Does the app bundle path change between Xcode and release. Any info would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files stored in the documents directory will not be removed during an app update. `FFUserPrefs.plist` is stored in the documents directory, so it will still be there after the update. Files stored in the app bundle (`[NSBundle mainBundle]`), however, will be replaced by the new bundle.

Comment: Dang that's what I was afraid of...ugh! Any suggestion on how I can preserve their data which is in /var/mobile/Applications/1111111A-111C-111E-111E-E1111111111/AppName.app/FFUserPrefs.plist before it gets replaced and move it to /Documents?

Comment: Isn't that what you're doing with `copyItemAtPath`? You're moving the PLIST file from the app bundle to the documents directory. Then all data will be written to the PLIST file in the documents directory. So the file in the documents directory, which contains all of the user data, will be safe while the blank template one in the bundle will be replaced.

Comment: You rock! I'm just freaking out and not even reading my own code right! One last question if you know...why would I lose the data from my release app when pushing the new version from Xcode? It wipes out everything.

Comment: Hmm... sometimes I have difficulty replacing apps that come from the App Store with ones signed with a development certificate. Can you try it again? There's no reason why anything should have been replaced.

Comment: Yep...just tested on my iPad and it replaced all the data too. I did have to change my development certificate to get it to run from iPhone Distribution to iPhone Developer if that would impact anything?